# Displaying multiple announcements

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint but I have been tasked with my departments site and I am struggling to find a solution for one issue.

I have a department site that is part of a larger organisation intranet site. We are using SharePoint 2013.

Within my department site I have created sub-sites for the different brands we work on. Each brand sub-site has it's own announcements app.

For the main section of my department site, I would like to collate all the announcements from each brand sub-site into a general announcement area for entire department.

Is this possible? Or am I overcomplicating something simple? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom solution for this kind of requirement. You can use SPSiteDataQuery to query the items present in Announcement kind of template. Once you have the data you can collate the data in one list based on your filter if any.

Read about SPSiteDataQuery and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content query webpart. have a look here for information how to use it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-dynamic-view-of-content-on-a-page-by-adding-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-3e35bd58-d159-43d6-bfc7-77878b4a856d

Answer (score 0):

There are two OOTB ways can achieve that. They both roll up information from subsites to top level site.

A. Content Query Web Part (CQWP)

(1) Drop a CQWP to page, edit web part.

[image] [image]

(2) Choose "Show item from all sites" and "Announcement List Type"

[image]

(3) You can also change the style under presentation

[image]

(PS. remember to change "Comments" to "Body" if you want to show the description.)

B. Content Search Web Part (CSWP)

(1) Go to all your Announcement List and turn on "Allow management of content types"

(2) Drop CSWP to page and edit web part

(3) Change query - Current site, items matching the content type, choose Announcement Content Type

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions!